# How to use python's selenium module to find all text information under a label, including the text of his sub-labels？

Tags: python, selenium

How do I find all the text content under a label?

```
<div class="Header1">
   <div class="contentHeader">
      <h3 id="select_printer_list_header">Select your printer model</h3>
      <div id="select_printer_list_info">Parameters are refined by the selected printer.</div>
      <div id="select_printer_list">
         <ul>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-J2000" style="display: list-item;">TM-J2000</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-J2100" style="display: list-item;">TM-J2100</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-L90" style="display: list-item;">TM-L90</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-L90_LFC" style="display: list-item;">TM-L90&nbsp;LFC</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-m10" style="display: list-item;">TM-m10</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-m30" style="display: list-item;">TM-m30</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-P20" style="display: list-item;">TM-P20</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-P60" style="display: list-item;">TM-P60</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-P60II" style="display: list-item;">TM-P60II</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-P80" style="display: list-item;">TM-P80</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-T20" style="display: list-item;">TM-T20</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-T20II" style="display: list-item;">TM-T20II</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-T20III" style="display: list-item;">TM-T20III</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-T20IIIL" style="display: list-item;">TM-T20IIIL</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-T20X" style="display: list-item;">TM-T20X</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-T70" style="display: list-item;">TM-T70</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-T70II" style="display: list-item;">TM-T70II</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-T81III" style="display: list-item;">TM-T81III</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-T82II" style="display: list-item;">TM-T82II</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-T82III" style="display: list-item;">TM-T82III</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-T82IIIL" style="display: list-item;">TM-T82IIIL</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-T82X" style="display: list-item;">TM-T82X</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-T83III" style="display: list-item;">TM-T83III</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-T88IV" style="display: list-item;">TM-T88IV</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-T88V" style="display: list-item;">TM-T88V</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-T88VI" style="display: list-item;">TM-T88VI</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-T90" style="display: list-item;">TM-T90</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-T100" style="display: list-item;">TM-T100</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-U220" style="display: list-item;">TM-U220</li>
            <li class="PrinterList TM-U230" style="display: list-item;">TM-U230</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <h1 class="Head-B" id="ht">HT</h1>
      <hr>
   </div>
   <div class="contentHeaderGhost"></div>
   <div class="Header2">
      <h2 class="Head-C">[Name]</h2>
      <div class="indent">
         <div>
            <div>Horizontal tab</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="Header2">
      <h2 class="Head-C">[Format]</h2>
      <div class="indent">
         <div>
            <table class="parameter">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td style="text-align:left;">
                        <div>
                           <div>ASCII</div>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                     <td style="">
                        <div>
                           <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                     <td style="">
                        <div>
                           <div>HT</div>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td style="text-align:left;">
                        <div>
                           <div>Hex</div>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                     <td style=""></td>
                     <td style="">
                        <div>
                           <div>09</div>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td style="text-align:left;">
                        <div>
                           <div>Decimal</div>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                     <td style=""></td>
                     <td style="">
                        <div>
                           <div>9</div>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="Header2">
      <h2 class="Head-C">[Description]</h2>
      <div class="indent">
         <div>
            <div>Moves the print position to the next horizontal tab position.</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="Header2">
      <h2 class="Head-C">[Notes]</h2>
      <div class="indent">
         <div>
            <ul class="disco">
               <li>
                  <div>This command is ignored unless the next horizontal tab position has been set.</div>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <div>If the next horizontal tab position exceeds the print area, the printer sets the print
                     position to [Print area width + 1].
                  </div>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <div>If this command is processed when the print position is at [Print area width + 1],
                     the printer executes <a href="index.php?content_id=7#glossary.pbuffulpr">Print buffer-full printing</a> of the current line and horizontal tab processing from the beginning of the next
                     line. In this case, in Page mode, the printer does not execute printing, but the print
                     position is moved.
                  </div>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <div>Horizontal tab positions are set by <a href="index.php?content_id=53#esc_cd">ESC D</a>.
                  </div>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <div>The printer will not be in the beginning of the line by executing this command.</div>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <div>When underline mode is turned on, the underline will not be printed under the tab
                     space skipped by this command.
                  </div>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

I use find_element_by_xpath (). I can only locate one element at a time, and it is difficult to find all the text. Find_elements_by_xpath ('// div [@ class = "pico_body"]') I have no way to accurately locate the element, how can I Do it to find all the text

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way to accomplish this type of tasks would be to use beautifulsoup. You can use ".text" method on a list of elements and store them in a string.